# Layout inspector does not work while running Android app in Debug mode

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-espresso, layout-inspector

My layout inspector does not work (aka does not renders the layout) when I am trying to run a UI Espresso test in DEBUG mode in Android Studio.

So when it's reaching my breakpoint the app just freezes and after a few click it will stops running with a crash that the app does not responding...

We have lots of dependency updates in our project (like kotlin, gradle plugin, etc.) and I also updated my Android Studio version from Bumblebee (2021.1.1) to Electric Eel (2022.1.1).

Before these changes I was able to put a breakpoint in a UI test and when it reached the breakpoint I was able to "continue" the scenario by manually clicking the app...
(I know that if I would put a breakpoint into the DEV code then it's normal for the app to freeze because I actually stopped the DEV code execution. But I think it should work with UI TEST code breakpoints, and it used to work, but now it doesn't).

What could be the problem?

I've tried cold boot, wipe data, using other devices (even tablet, phone, landscape, portrait, different api levels, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you suspend all threads instead of the thread at the breakpoint. This setting can be change by right clicking on the breakpoint.

Suspending only the thread will solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: It really works, this was the problem. Thanks!

Seems like in the newer Android Studios (~above Dolphin) the breakpoints suspending all the threads by default, so I needed to tick back the 'Thread' and make it as default.